# Significance of wildcard in elastic query

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

In elastic search when I search for
*mysearch and only 
mysearch

the result set is same. But *mysearch takes a lot of time.

So what is the significance of wildcard over here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*` character is called a wildcard and allows you to search terms that "end with" something, e.g. `*mysearch` will search for terms that end with `mysearch`

Wildcard searches are usually more expensive because all the terms need to be examined as explained in the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_wildcards) for the `query_string` query (which Kibana uses under the hood)

> Allowing a wildcard at the beginning of a word (eg "*ing") is
>   particularly heavy, because all terms in the index need to be
>   examined, just in case they match. Leading wildcards can be disabled
>   by setting allow_leading_wildcard to false.

Comment: *mysearch does not mean searches that end with mysearch. it means mysearch prepended with anything. It need not be ending.

For me *mysearch and mysearch return the same result-set

Comment: Can you show examples where you can find `mysearch` in the middle of a word?

Comment: Okay, got it. I got it confused with SQL wildcard. When I searched for *mysearch it used to match results like:-
"This is test-mysearch and result". 
I thought * here is matching "Test is test-". So had a doubt - 
what is matching " and result"
Thanks